# Why does an uninstalled Canon LBP 5050 printer keep reappearing?

Tags: mac, printing, macos, canon

I used to have a Canon LBP 5050. It is no longer connected to the network or the Mac. I removed the printer from: "System Preferences → Printers" and even removed the `ppd` from `/Library/Printers`, using Terminal, but for some reason it constantly reinstalls itself every time I reboot my machine.

As far as I can tell there is no special Canon software installed or gets "called up" as a logon item.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How was the printer connected? USB directly? Via an Airport device? Using a network printer server?

Comment: LAN using the IP-Adress

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat of a hidden feature, you might want to try resetting the printing system.

- Go to the Print and Scan preference pane.
- Right click in the list of available printers (mine's empty).
- Select "Reset printing system...".

[image: print and scan prefpane]